# Google Maps Javascript API "Failed to Load Resource" issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am getting issues with Google Maps not allowing me to calculate distances on a Ruler tool I have created using Polyline.

This did work perfectly, but I am now getting the error "Failed to Load Resource" in the console.

The resources failing to load look like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=mt:m,c:22.976313%2C-18.984375,sp:57.44697x119.17969,src:apiv3,ts:3pl5t8

Any insight to this would be really helpful.

PS: I did notice here http://api-status.com/6404/116028 that there is Service Disruption.

Comment: Recently have been getting the same problem.